# How to make image layer visible in openlayers

Tags: javascript, visibility, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using OpenLayers with OpenStreetMaps to develop a small GIS-application. 
The image overlay doesn't seem to be working when isBaseLayer is set to false, here is my code:

```
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
                    eventListeners: {
                        "moveend": mapEvent,
                        "zoomend": mapEvent
                    }
                });
  OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Toolserver = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, {
      initialize: function(name, options) {
          var url = [
              "http://a.www.toolserver.org/tiles/" + name + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", 
              "http://b.www.toolserver.org/tiles/" + name + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", 
              "http://c.www.toolserver.org/tiles/" + name + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
              "http://d.www.toolserver.org/tiles/" + name + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
              "http://e.www.toolserver.org/tiles/" + name + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
              "http://f.www.toolserver.org/tiles/" + name + "/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"
          ];
          options = OpenLayers.Util.extend({numZoomLevels: 19}, options);
          OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [name, url, options]);
      },
      CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Toolserver"
  });
  l1=new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Toolserver('osm-labels-de', {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true});
  l2=new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Toolserver('osm-no-labels', {isBaseLayer: true, visibility: true});
  var pic = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
    'shot',
    'shot.jpg',
    new OpenLayers.Bounds(13.409460,52.5207532,13.469466,52.5407532),    new OpenLayers.Size(100, 100),
    {alwaysInRange:true,isBaseLayer: false,transparent: true, visibility: true,numZoomLevels : 3 }
  );
  map.addLayers([pic,l1,l2]);
  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.409460,52.5207532).transform(
          new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
          map.getProjectionObject()
          ),10);
```

The Layer "pic" should appear between layers "l1" and "l2" (When replacing pic with a KML-Layer, it works just fine) - BUT it appears nowhere - i am not sure, whether it is a coordinate problem or something else.

The problem could be simplified to just one base-layer "l2" and overlaying "pic" above it - i can't accomplish this either.

I saw the example at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/image-layer.html but there, the image is the baselayer - when i set isBaseLayer to false, the image disappears. I don't really mind setting the image to be the baselayer but if i do, ONLY the image is visible, no maps anymore.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the problem is the lack of transformation of the bounds of the 'pic' layer.
In your code you use the `transform` method to set the map centre. In the exact way you must use it for the 'pic' layer's bounds.

Please check out the code I use to set an image layer on a map:

```
    // World Geodetic System 1984 projection (lon/lat)
    var projWGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

    var options = {   
        opacity: 1.0, 
        isBaseLayer: false,
        numZoomLevels: 20 
    };

    var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(WEST,SOUTH,EAST,NORTH)
        .transform(projWGS84, map.getProjectionObject());

    var imageLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image('Image Layer',  
        'http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/04/19/20120419_Java_Duke_mascot_001_610x418.jpg', 
        extent,
        new OpenLayers.Size(1,1),
        options);
```